# Is it possible to have 10Gigabit network support on a macOS VM?

Tags: network, virtualization, parallels-desktop

We're looking to have macOS VMs running on Mac Mini hosts (and maybe Mac Pro hosts once they're out).

Is it possible to have the VMs connected at 10Gig ethernet by using something like a Sonnet 10G Thunderbolt 3 Adapter? Would Parallels support something like this? What if I would plug in several of those adapters, could each VM use a different 10G adapter?

Comment: I know for sure VMware‘s product supports this. I’m not going to address parallels in my answer because I don’t have recent experience, but I can’t imagine if an adapter worked with macOS it would not work into parallels as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a trial license (free) of VMWare ESXi to enable hardware support for USB-C and Thunderbolt adapters.

- https://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2017/01/functional-usb-c-thunderbolt-3-ethernet-adapter-for-esxi-5-5-6-0-6-5.html
- https://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2019/04/new-thunderbolt-3-to-10gbe-options-for-esxi.html

There are many home labs where thunderbolt to 10G Ethernet and 8G Fiber work even when those adapters are not on the official hardware compatibility and support matrix. Newer Mac mini have 10 GB Ethernet built in as well. I’ve never seen a 10 gig link saturate, so we just put several VM on the same hardware in practice.

- https://www.virtuallyghetto.com/tag/thunderbolt-3

Until we’ve got fast enough NVMe storage, I can’t imagine needing more than one ten gig ethernet adapter unless I was doing rack mounted workstations and enterprise class servers.